# Find USSD Code From Query String

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I'm working on a mobile recharge portal in asp.net with C#. Mobile Operator Hit my provided url for recharge with USSD code and other parameter and I read the parameter respond theme our response. Here my problem is with USSD code. because USSD code has (#)value and when I'm accessing parameter on server side unable to read values after(#). Is there any other way to read all query string value(by javascript or any other) and post it to server side?
any help will be appreciated. thanks in advance.
Below is  my url with parameters

```
http://192.168.1.1/page.aspx??dlg_id=1233&short_code=*123*1#&req_text=1&msisdn=93987654320&session_id=USSD1234&concat_req_string=987*1#&date_time=&circle_id=0019&dcs=0&curr_menu=MENU
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Url encode the query in the browser with javascript and decode on the server.

```
var uri = "dlg_id=1233&short_code=*123*1#&req_text=1&msisdn=93987654320&session_id=USSD1234&concat_req_string=987*1#&date_time=&circle_id=0019&dcs=0&curr_menu=MENU";
var res = encodeURI(uri);
```

The result would be:

```
dlg_id%3D1233%26short_code%3D*123*1%23%26req_text%3D1%26msisdn%3D93987654320%26session_id%3DUSSD1234%26concat_req_string%3D987*1%23%26date_time%3D%26circle_id%3D0019%26dcs%3D0%26curr_menu%3DMENU
```

Comment: Thank PepitoSh but Our Operator is not ready to any change . is there any other solution at my end

Comment: I checked your query in Chrome. The browser does not send the full query, it stops at the first #. I didn't know this is how this works. I think you are out of luck.